# jQuery buttons to change background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, background, hover

I'd like to create a series of buttons.  When the user hovers over the buttons, I'd like to display different images in the background.  The transition between bg images should be a smooth crossfade.

I've pasted a little bit of code to show my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/Rk4YG/

Note: It'd be nice to stop the background image from being selectable - does that mean using css background-image?

If anyone can please help me write some code to achieve this, or point me in the right direction of a good tutorial, I'd be incredibly grateful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The jsfiddle code was a big help. +1 for including it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that may get you started:

**HTML**

We use the HTML5 data attributes to store the name of each background image. These are retreived later using the jQuery `.attr()` function.

```
<div role="main" class="mid"></div>
<div class="btncontain">
    <div class="btn btn1" data-bg-img="image0.png"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn2" data-bg-img="image1.png"><a href="#">Button 2</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn3" data-bg-img="image2.png"><a href="#">Button 3</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn4" data-bg-img="image3.png"><a href="#">Button 4</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn5" data-bg-img="image4.png"><a href="#">Button 5</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn6" data-bg-img="image5.png"><a href="#">Button 6</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn7" data-bg-img="image6.png"><a href="#">Button 7</a></div>
    <div class="btn btn8" data-bg-img="image7.png"><a href="#">Button 8</a></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

The `.mid`  now sits behind the buttons. Both are absolutley positioned to get the layering right.

```
body { padding: 0; margin:0; }
.mid { width:100%; height: 700px; position:absolute; }
.btncontain { width:80%; margin: 0 auto; position:absolute; }
.btn a { width: 150px; height: 70px; background: yellow; float: left; margin: 0 30px 100px 30px; }
.mid { background-image: url(image0.png);
```

**JavaScript**

The jQuery animate function fades in `div.mid` over the top of the background. Once it's 100% opaque, then we switch the background image to the new one and hide `div.mid`.

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn a').parents('.btn').hover(function(){
      var  img = $(this).attr('data-bg-img'),
           afterFadeIn = function() {
               $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
               $('mid').css('opacity', 0);
           };
      $('.mid')
          .css({'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')', 'opacity': 0})
          .animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 500, afterFadeIn);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've just given this a test in jsfiddle with some google image references in place of the .png's, but the hover does not seem to work.  Is there any chance you could help me find the issue?